# Updating the Perm Gen Memory Jenkins - MacOSX

Tags: macos, jenkins

I am trying to update the Perm Gen Memory in Jenkins, from what I have read adding this to the `org.jenkins.plist` file would do the trick but it is not changing it for me:

```
<key>-XX:PermSize</key>
<string>512m</string>
<key>-XX:MaxPermSize</key>
<string>1024m</string>
```

When I use the Jenkins monitoring tool is still tells me that:

```
Perm Gen Memory: 81mb
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/02/01/jenkins-ci-server-on-osx, you should be using **<string>** but not **<key>**, eg:

```
<string>-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</string>
```

<key> denotes a section.  In this case, you are setting program arguments that fall under the **<key>ProgramArguments</key>** section.  What you specified as key sections is probably confusing the launcher.  Look at that link for a complete example and compare to yours.

Abridged example:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    ..... more props here...
    <string>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</string>
    .... more props here
  </array>
  ... more stuff here...
</dict>
```

Also note the instructions for **properly restarting** (unloading/loading) the instance so that the changes are applied.  Once you restart it, confirm that the options you set translated properly to the command line:

```
ps aux | grep java
```

The properties should be properly formatted as follows:

```
-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped, though once i restarted the instance I still could not see either option `-XX:PermSize=512m` nor `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`